# Ipad is not showing directory created with phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, ionic-framework

I created one directory using:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Folder1", {create: true}, function (dir) {});
});
```

However, the directory is not displayed on my Ipad. I have tried using the file manager, but the directory is not displayed as well.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: what do you expect to happen? that code only get the folder, but doesn't display anything

Comment: Need to show that folder in Ipad file manager, but not display in that.

Comment: fileSystem API doesn't show anything, you have to create and display the folders with HTML

Comment: Means to create folder view in same app and display it? But need to display in file manager, is it possible? 
I have capture photo and store in folder but it not display in photo app.